# How can I get the most popular item in a group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, series

I have a Pandas Dataframe containing cars for sale and I'd like to get the most popular for each brand, however I seem unable to do this.

I have a pandas dataframe with some columns (e.g: vehicle type, price, mileage, year, brand, model, etc) and for each car brand, I'd like to check which model occurs  the most.
I've tried to use a groupby, like this:

```
popular_models = dataset.groupby('brand').model.value_counts().groupby(level=0).nlargest(1)
```

But it returns a Pandas Series in which some of the data I want is stored in the indices and it also adds one repeated column that is not making any sense to me.

I'd like to get a a DataFrame containing 3 columns, like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXw4b.jpg)

However, I'm getting a pandas series like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iviA.jpg)

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to groupby both objects you want to keep, then count the one you want to find the occurrences of. Here is the example input file:

```
Brand   Model
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Acura   RDX
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
Beach   Baby
BMW     320i
BMW     320i
BMW     320i
BMW     320i
BMW     320i
BMW     320i
BMW     320i
BMW     550i
BMW     550i
BMW     550i
BMW     550i
BMW     550i
BMW     550i
BMW     550i
Cadillac        Escalade
Cadillac        Escalade
Cadillac        Escalade
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
Chana   Cargo
```

The simple pandas one liner:

```
df = pd.read_table('fun.txt', header=0)
print(df.groupby(['Brand','Model'])['Model'].agg(['count']))
```

And the output:

```
                   count
Brand    Model
Acura    RDX          10
BMW      320i          7
         550i          7
Beach    Baby         10
Cadillac Escalade      3
Chana    Cargo        12
```

If you want to sort the values by frequency (largest to smallest) and keep only the largest change the one-liner to:

```
groupby_df = (df.groupby(['Brand','Model'])['Model'].agg(['count']).sort_values(by='count', ascending=False).reset_index().drop_duplicates('Brand', keep='first'))
```

to get:

```
      Brand     Model  count
0     Chana     Cargo     12
1     Acura       RDX     10
2     Beach      Baby     10
3       BMW      320i      7
5  Cadillac  Escalade      3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I think you forgot to add the code that sorts the values. You just wrote: "If you want to sort the values by frequency (largest to smallest) change the one-liner to:" but never showed the actual code. Another question: how can I keep just the most frequent model for each brand (discarding all the others)?

Comment: I will update to show how to keep the most frequent model.

Comment: updated the answer to show how to keep only the highest frequency model by brand.

Comment: If there are 2 models with the same count, it will keep the one that comes first in the sort

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to sort and then drop duplicates after a `groupby` operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Brand': ['B1'] * 5 + ['B2'] * 5,
                   'Model': ['M1', 'M2', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3',
                             'N1', 'N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N1']})

df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Model'])['Model'].transform('count')

res = df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)\
        .drop_duplicates('Brand')

print(res)

#   Brand Model  Count
# 5    B2    N1      3
# 0    B1    M1      2
```

Note this removes duplicate groupwise top counts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.

1. Setup the DataFrameGroupBy object:

   `df.groupby(["Brand", "Model"])`
2. Use the GroupBy `size` function to compute sizes of each subgroup (returns as a Series):

   `df.groupby(["Brand", "Model"]).size()`
3. Convert back into DataFrame while naming the column containing the values computed by `size`:

   `df.groupby(["Brand", "Model"]).size().reset_index(name="Count")`
4. Sort the DataFrame in descending order by the `Count` of subgroup items:

   `df.groupby(["Brand", "Model"]).size().reset_index(name="Count").sort_values(by="Count", ascending=False)`
5. Drop duplicate `Brand` values keeping the first entry in the DataFrame:

   `df.groupby(["Brand", "Model"]).size().reset_index(name="Count").sort_values(by="Count", ascending=False).drop_duplicates("Brand", keep="first")`